# Term Document Sparse Matrix new

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

Hello all I am currently going through a python internship and have no clue on how to even begin this term document sparse matrix. I have worked on looping through the files and making and list of all the words in the files. I have no clue on how to make a matrix like this. Please help me get started or some guidance. Thank you so much. [image]

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-term_matrix

Comment: Then go here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: Then go here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html